# mysql: simpler and more efficient query for getting unique products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I would like to optimize my database query but I am not sure how to do this.

I want to get a list of stores' products opinions, ordered by opinion dates (from newest to oldest ones), but the products need to be unique.

*For example, there are 3 users:* **U1**, **U2**, **U3**.

*There are 2 stores in the city:*

- **S1** (*with products* P11, P12, P13, P14)
- **S2** (*with products* P21, P22, P23, P24)

Users added some opinions (the newest on the top, the oldest on the bottom):

```
U1: P22
U1: P13
U2: P21
U3: P13
U2: P23
U1: P23
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
U1: P22
U1: P13
U2: P21
U2: P23
```

The query I created is very long and a bit complicated. Could I simplify it somehow?

```
$sql_query = "
SELECT a.*
     , b.name AS 'store_name'
     , b.city AS 'store_city'
     , c.name AS 'product_name'
  FROM `app_products_opinion` AS a 
  JOIN `app_products_stores` AS b 
    ON a.store_ID = b.ID 
  JOIN `app_products` AS c 
    ON a.product_ID = c.ID 
 WHERE a.created_on IN
    (
        SELECT max(created_on) as created_on
        FROM app_products_opinion
        WHERE show_on_list='1' AND (added_by='".$_SESSION["CMSUserID"]."' OR status = '1')
        GROUP by product_ID
        ORDER by created_on DESC
     ) 
     AND a.show_on_list='1' 
     AND a.store_ID='".$id_store['ID']."' $addtosql 
     AND a.photo != '' 
     AND (a.added_by='".$_SESSION["CMSUserID"]."' OR a.status='1') 
     ORDER BY a.created_on DESC
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try  grouping  by product_id and also joining by product_ID and date
(simplified  code)

```
 SELECT a.user_id, a.product_ID 
 from app_products_opinion a 
 INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT product_ID, max(created_on) as created_on
    FROM app_products_opinion
    WHERE show_on_list='1' AND (added_by='".$_SESSION["CMSUserID"]."' OR status = '1')
    GROUP by product_ID
    ORDER by created_on DESC
 ) t on a.created_on = t.created_on 
    AND a.product_ID = t.product_ID
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you think it's simpler (and ignoring, $addtosql) but you could do this...

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.name AS 'store_name'
     , b.city AS 'store_city'
     , c.name AS 'product_name'
  FROM `app_products_opinion` AS a 
  JOIN `app_products_stores` AS b 
    ON a.store_ID = b.ID 
  JOIN `app_products` AS c 
    ON a.product_ID = c.ID 
  JOIN
     (
      SELECT product_id
           , max(created_on) created_on
        FROM app_products_opinion
       WHERE show_on_list = 1
         AND (added_by = 'M' OR status = 1)
       GROUP 
          by product_ID
      )  x
      ON a.created_on = x.created_on
     AND a.product_id = x.product_id
     AND a.show_on_list = 1
     AND a.store_ID = 'N'  
     AND a.photo != '' 
     AND (a.added_by = 'Z' OR a.status = 1)
```